# How to find out if object has attributes?

Tags: python

```
 if groupName.group == "None":
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How to check if object has an attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `groupName` itself is `None`.

In which case, there's little point in testing whether it has a particular attribute.

So you probably want something more like:

```
If groupName is not None:
    print groupName.group
```

Or, if `groupName` objects may not have a `group` attribute:

```
If groupName is not None:
    print getattr(groupName, 'group', None)
```

(Note: the last argument of [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) is a default value that can be anything you want).

Answer (score 9):

You want [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr), which you can pass a default value, or [`hasattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you call "to have an attribute".

.

### `hasattr()`

If you want to verify if an expression `X.a` will return something or raise an error, you can use `hasattr()`

```
def f(x,y):
    return x+y
f.a = 'suming function'
print "hasattr(f,'a') : ",hasattr(f,'a'),'     f.a : ',f.a
print "hasattr(f,'sdjk') : ",hasattr(f,'sdjk'),'     f.sdjk : ',f.sdjk
```

produces

```
hasattr(f,'a') :  True      f.a :  suming function
hasattr(f,'sdjk') :  False      f.sdjk : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\all\aaaaa.py", line 26, in <module>
    print "hasattr(f,'sdjk') : ",hasattr(f,'sdjk'),'     f.sdjk : ',f.sdjk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sdjk'
```

.

### `__dict__`

But it may happen that calling an attribute on an instance with a certain name returns something while there is not really this name in the namespace of the instance, that is to say no item `name:object` in the dictionary of this instance's attributes.

It's the case with a class attribute : a class attribute is returned when a call of its name is done on one of  the instances of the class, while this name doesn't exist in the namespace of the instance.  See example:

```
class Tomo:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Tomo.count += 1
    pass

ti = Tomo()
ta = Tomo()
tu = Tomo()
ty = Tomo()
print 'ty.count ==',ty.count,"       hasattr(ty,'count') ==",hasattr(ty,'count')
print 'ty.__dict__ ==',ty.__dict__,"   'count' in ty.__dict__ ==",'count' in ty.__dict__
print
```

result

```
ty.count == 4        hasattr(ty,'count') == True
ty.__dict__ == {}    'count' in ty.__dict__ == False
```

So
`hasattr(ty,'count')` says *"YES"*
while `'count' in ty.__dict__` says *"NO, ty doesn't have an attribute **count**"* .

.

**Then**, asking `hasattr(object,name)` gives less precise answer on the state of the real objects in a program than asking `name in object.__dict__`, though **hasattr()**  gives more pertinent information concerning the treatment of data that is the practical aim of running a program.

So , I think that use of `hasattr()` is rather associated to the algorithm , and use of `__dict__` rather associated to the comprehension of the underlying mechanisms of a running program.

.

### dir()

Theoretically `dir(object)` gives the keys of the dictionnary `__dict__` of the object.
But

> dir([object])  Without arguments, return the list of names in the
>   current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of
>   valid attributes for that object. If the object does not provide
>   `__dir__()` , the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s
>   `__dict__` attribute, if defined, **and from its type object**

Hence, there is the same problem with `dir()` than with `hasattr()` : it gives more attributes than the only ones being exactly in an object and not in its parent classes.

.

---

.

By the way, I presume it will be OK if you do:

```
if hasattr(groupName,'group') and groupName.group is None:
    ..........
    .....
    ........
```

It is said that it's better to use `is` for testing None than `==`

Answer (score 2):

Python follows the [EAFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) motto, so it is claimed to be better style just to try and handle an exception.

So try

```
try:
    gr = groupName.group
except AttributeError:
    complain()
else:
    if gr == "None":
        go_on()
```

But beware: I'm not sure if your `== "None"` is what you want. Maybe `is None` would be the thing...

Answer (score 1):

In python there's a motto: Better to Say Sorry than Ask Permission. I would suggest to find out what are your needs and eventually do something like:

```
try:
  # do something with groupName.group

except SomeException, e: ...
  # act some other way
```